# Jquery function appending to empty div

Tags: jquery, append

I am currently trying to teach myself some coding, and I am following along on a lesson of how to make a stopwatch.  So far I have gotten everything to work, except when I hit the lap button it is not taking the laptime and appending it to an empty div.  Any ideas?

This is the function I am trying to use:

```
function addLap(){
    var myLapDetails = "<div>Lap</div>";
    $("#myLapDetails").appendTo("#laps");
}
```

This is where I am trying to place it:

```
<div id="laps">
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a jQuery element from a string and use it like so:

```js
function addLap() {
  var $myLapDetails = $("<div>Lap</div>");
  $myLapDetails.appendTo("#laps");
}

addLap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="laps"></div>
```

Note the `$` in the variable name is not required but is considered "idiomatic" jQuery if there is such a thing.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `$("#myLapDetails")` is looking for an existing element that has `id="myLapDetails"` that doesn't exist.

You can append the string as variable.

```js
function addLap() {
  var myLapDetails = "<div>Lap</div>";
  $("#laps").append(myLapDetails);
}

addLap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="laps"></div>
```